# I am having difficulties with creating an equipment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating an equipment and I have two actions in my equipment controller, `new` and `create`.. and I have two views which is new and a partial form..

I also have four tables.. which are `equipments`, `equipment_types`, `equipment_locations`, and `equipment_management_informations`..

The form looks like..

```
>= error_messages_for 'equipment'
%table.contentText{:style => "width: 100%"}
  - if @types
    %tr
      %td Equipment Type
      %td= collection_select 'equipment', 'equipment_type_id', @types,  :id, :name, {}, :class => "dropdownSelect"
  %tr
    %td Location
    %td= select 'equipment', 'equipment_location_id', @equipment_locations.collect { |e| ["#{e.name.capitalize!}", e.id]},{}, :class => "dropdownSelect"
  %tr
    %td Serial Number
    %td= text_field 'equipment', 'serial_number', :class => 'textFields'
  %tr
    %td MAC Address
    %td= text_field 'equipment', 'mac_address', :class => 'textFields'
  %tr
    %td IP Address
    %td= text_field 'equipment', 'ip_address', :class => 'textFields'
  - if @stands
    %tr
      %td Stand
      %td= collection_select 'equipment', 'stand_id', @stands, :id, :street_no, :include_blank => true
  %tr
    %td{:valign => 'top'} Description
    %td= text_area 'equipment', 'description', :cols => 45, :rows => '3', :class => "txt_area_effect"
```

and my new view is like:

```
> %h3 New equipment
%div{:style => "border: 1px solid #CCC;"}
  - form_tag :action => 'create', :estate_id => @estate do
    = render :partial => 'form'
    = submit_tag "Create"
    - action = "list"
    %input{:type => "button", :value => "Back", :onclick => "window.location='#{action}';", :class => "start"}
```

and my create action display this a nil when i inspect it

```
   @equipment = Equipment.find(params[:equipment])
```

it gives an error like

```
 Unknown key(s): equipment_type_id, mac_address, description, equipment_location_id, serial_number, ip_address
```

Comment: What attributes/columns has Your model Equipment?

Comment: all of the unknown key(s). but anyway way thanks i figured out the solution..on my action create i mistakenly wrote  @equipment = Equipment.find(params[:equipment])
instead of  @equipment = Equipment.new(params[:equipment])

Comment: Good to hear the problem is solved! ;)

Comment: You may want to add an answer or indicate the problem is now solved at the start of your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
@equipment = Equipment.find(params[:equipment])
```

should be:

```
@equipment = Equipment.new(params[:equipment])
```

or

```
@equipment = Equipment.new(params[:equipment])
```

(just posting answer from comments so this stops showing as unanswered)